# Matlab data type inconsistence for cursor.data when running matlab code in MCR and Matlab studio

Tags: database, matlab, cursor

I have a piece of matlab code below which reads data from a table. When I run this code in Matlab studio, the cursor.data type is cell array. But when I use my Java code to run this code in MCR, the `cursor.data` type is double. My Matlab Studio version is 2012a. My MCR version now is 2011b. I'm trying to upgrade my MCR version to 2012a. Besides the possible version issue, does anybody know other possible reason which causes this issue? Thanks!

```
cur = exec(conn, ['SELECT CAST(Customer_Key AS NUMERIC(38,6)), ...
           CAST(Product_Key AS NUMERIC(38,6)), Spend FROM ' inputTable]);
cursor = fetch(cur);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a configuration issue.  Check the docs for [setdbprefs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/database/ug/setdbprefs.html) to see options.

```
setdbprefs('datareturnformat','cellarray')
```

You may need to set the config option explicitly like this.

Comment: I didn't config any database preferences. I was surprised to see this inconsistency in MCR and Matlab studio.

Comment: I've never used MCR; it's possible the default configuration is just different.